# How do binary trees facilitate compiling expressions into machine language

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

> Binary trees facilitate high-speed searching and sorting of data,
>   eliminating duplicate data items efficiently, representing file-system
>   directories, **compiling expressions into machine language** and many
>   other interesting applications.

This is from Java How to Program 9th Edition.

I just don't get **How do binary trees facilitate compiling expressions into machine language?**

Comment: Read carefully.  The text doesn't say that binary trees compile expressions they "facilitate ... compiling expressions into machine language".  Anyway, I think this one refers to Abstract Syntax Trees.

Comment: I have little to say which Voktor Seifert didn't already say, but this excerpt seems suspicious, which leads me to doubt the quality of the book. File systems use trees, but not binary trees; the search trees the first two use cases allude to can be (and are, in fact) implemented for trees with any arity, and being binary doesn't imply being balanced (which is necessary for "high-speed"); and ASTs are usually not binary but of variable arity. In short, that piece appears to oversell binary trees (as opposed to be more general concept of trees of any arity).

Comment: I second @delnan's concerns.  This statement is like saying _"socket wrenches facilitate high-speed rail, oil exploration and construction of tall skyscrapers"_.  It's all true but essentially meaningless.  Binary trees exist at the "socket wrench" level in the software toolkit, and are useful for tons of things.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert I am sorry I edited it.

Comment: @delnan For me I can find the book has a very good material. I am not very experienced with data structures in general or trees specifically because this is my first programming course in fact. I just understand how it facilitates the sorting and searching data, eliminating duplicated elements and I thought about file-system directories are represented as trees but didn't really thought about whether they're binary or not and about compiling expressions there are exercises that ask for implementing complete working compiler in the book which may explain more about this.

Comment: @JimGarrison Your comment actually helped me understanding it well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize / recapitulate the comments:

- Binary trees "facilitate" compiling expressions, in the same sense that bricks "facilitate" house building.  You can use bricks to build houses, *ergo* they "facilitate" building houses.
- This piece of text is largely content free.  My guess it is part of an introductory paragraph that is intended to whet your appetite for some example involving binary trees<sup>1</sup> that is coming a in a paragraph or so.
- Without reading the book ... the kind of homogeneous binary trees that (I predict) he is about to describe are not really suitable for representing expressions in a compiler.  Abstract syntax trees (ASTs) are typically neither binary or homogeneous.  Rather, there are most likely lots of different node types, and different node types have different numbers and types of child nodes.
- There is nothing *useful* to be learned from that bit of text.  Move along.  Nothing happening here.  :-)

<sup>1 - But don't expect a detailed explanation of compilers.  That is *way* beyond the scope of a introductory programming textbook.  Indeed, I wouldn't even expect a decent coverage of "data structures".</sup>

Comment: I already noticed that there are many exercises that ask for implementing a complete working compiler like step by step. May be I will know then what this means. anyways thanks for your answer!